# public static class & constructor

Tags: c#

I'm facing this weird issue, the constrcutor doesnt seem to be called. Any idea why?

```
public static class GetClaims
    {
        public static string tenantid { get; set; }
        public static string username { get; set; }
        public static bool isauthenticated { get; set; }

        static GetClaims()
        {
            ClaimsPrincipal incomingPrincipal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal;
            if (incomingPrincipal != null && incomingPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
            {
                ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = incomingPrincipal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
                username = claimsIdentity.Name;
                isauthenticated = claimsIdentity.IsAuthenticated;
                if (claimsIdentity.IsAuthenticated == true)
                {
                    tenantid = incomingPrincipal.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    tenantid = "bla";
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

from another normal class:

```
query =  $"UPDATE [DB].[dbo].[CustomerData-{GetClaims.tenantid}] SET ....
```

Comment: I cannot see a constructor in the class. Replace static with public and it's a contructor.

Comment: oh, and I see now. Static classes don't have constructors.

Comment: A static constructor gets called the first time you access any member of the class, so it should be called when the `query` string gets constructed. How do you determine it's not being called? Also please construct a [mcve]

Comment: @fredrik I guess they were wrong in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors) then

Comment: wow, never used that. so I actually didn't know. Personally I can see no valid use case for static classes like that.

Comment: OP, is the principal then there and authenticated at the time you use your code? How many users do you expect? The static constructor will be called exactly once, so it will be set exactly once in the lifetime of the application (unless ofcourse when it is not an authenticated user when it is called the first time)

Comment: @Icepickle I did not know that, I thought it was per session. Static constructor is not what I'm looking for then. If i create another static void in the static class, does that get called for each user session?

Comment: @UnholySheep because the string returns null, and when I debug the static class it doesnt pause

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the original poster is looking for explanations of beliefs about static constructors which are false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is really no valid reason to write this particular example the way you do it here.

For one, if you read up on [static constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors) you would see that a static constructor gets called exactly once throughout the lifetime of the application.

So your code will be valid for the very first user to trigger the static constructor.

Even if this wasn't enough of a downside, you have the problem that anybody can set the static properties that you have created, so it doesn't give you a lot of certainty that these are really coming from the database.

If you really want to keep it as a static method, then give it a return type and a `ClaimsPrincipal` as input

```
public static class ClaimsManager
{
    public static UserIdentityState GetClaims( ClaimsPrincipal principal )
    {
        if (principal == null || !principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return UserIdentityState.NotAuthenticated;
        }
        return new UserIdentityState {
            Name =  principal.Identity.Name,
            TenantId = incomingPrincipal.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid")?.Value,
            IsAuthenticated = true
        };
    }
}
```

Which you could then use inside your query part, by using for example

```
// at the using statements
using static ClaimsManager;

//... in your query statement

var claims = GetClaims( Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal );
if (!claims.IsAuthenticated) {
  return;
}
query =  $"UPDATE [DB].[dbo].[CustomerData-{claims.TenantId}] SET .... ";
```

Ofcourse you would still have to have an implementation of the `UserIdentityState` class that I am proposing and a static method for that class that returns a `NotAuthenticated` user

Answer (score 0):

I doesn't seem that your class should be static. I think is should look more like the following snippet.

```
public class GetClaims
{
    public string Tenantid { get; }
    public string Username { get; }
    public bool Isauthenticated { get; }


    GetClaims()
    { 
       ...
    }
}
```

## Static constructors

[Static constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors) are called only once, in normal circumstances.

```
public class C {
    static C() { Console.WriteLine("Static!");} 
    public C() { Console.WriteLine("Instance!");}
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var c1 = new C();
        var c2 = new C();
    }
```

```
Static!
Instance!
Instance!
```